# Objective-C multiple class definitions in one .h and .m

Tags: objective-c

I have two subclasses, one that has a lot of customization, we'll call it Foo, and another sub class that only needs 1 method overridden, and doesn't need any additional variables, we'll call it Bar.

Bar will be one of the variables of Foo, so to keep from having 2 more files to work with (.m and .h for Bar) I would like to interface and implement Bar in Foo's .h and .m files.

My best effort gives me several compiler errors.

The .h file looks like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Foo : FooSuperClass {
    Bar *barVariable;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Bar *barVariable;

-(void) fooMethod;
@end

@interface Bar : BarSuperClass {
}

@end
```

The .m file looks like:

```
#import "Foo.h"


@implementation Foo
@synthesize barVariable;

-(void) fooMethod{
  //do foo related things
}
@end

@implementation Bar
- (void)barSuperClassMethodIWantToOverride{
}
@end
```

I realize that this type of things would generally be frowned upon, but I feel it's appropriate in my situation.  The first error I get is "expected specifier-qualifier-list before Bar".

What have I done wrong, I'm pretty sure it's possible to have multiple declarations/definitions in a single file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your header you've used `Bar` before declaring it. Solution: Put `Bar`'s definition before `Foo`'s.

Comment: It's often better to use the `@class` directive. For instance, what happens if you then have an instance variable of type `Foo` declared in `Bar`?

Answer (score 30):

The compiler only considers types valid that it has seen before.  As Nikolai mentioned, you could declare `Bar` before `Foo`.

However, that isn't always possible.  For other situations, you can use `@class` to forward declare the class.

I.e.

```
@class Bar;
@interface Foo : NSObject
{
    Bar *bar;
}
@end
```

`@class Bar;` tells the compiler that there exists a class named Bar and pointers to Bar should be considered valid.